# JQuery - Retrieve value from another child element of the same parent

Tags: jquery

I'm fairly new to JQuery and am having trouble with something that I'm sure is simple.  Here is an example of some html that I'm working with:

```
<tr>
<td><div class="testclass"><p>Test text</p></div></td>
<td><button class="testButton">Button text</button></td>
</tr>​
```

When the button is clicked, I want to get the value in `<p>` in a previous cell.  Here's how I'm currently trying to select it:

```
var text = $(".testButton").parent().parent().closest('p').text();
```

Within the `onClick` function of the button, I've also tried:

```
$(this).prev('p').text();
```

However, it's always `null`.  I've messed around with jsfiddle for a little while trying to get this right, but no luck.  Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try use:

```
$(".testButton").click(function(){
 alert($(this).parent().parent().find('p').text());
});
```

demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/ZsLZ2/

Answer (score 2):

Why not

```
var text = $(".testButton").parent().prev().find('p').text();
```

Note that if you have many buttons, you should use $(this) to select the good one :

```
$('.testButton').click(function(){
    var text = $(this).parent().prev().find('p').text();
    alert(text);
});​
```

[DEMONSTRATION](http://jsfiddle.net/DZPRc/)

Comment: For some reason the text() value on this still displays null in jsfiddle, but it's definitely close.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you can make use of [siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/):

```
$('.testButton').click(function() {
    alert($(".testButton").siblings().text())
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/3a69A/

Comment: Thanks - haven't used siblings() before.  I'll check it out.